# Add custom lines to Nginx config with Vagrant / Homestead

Tags: laravel, nginx, vagrant, homestead

I'm running an Nginx server on a Vagrant Homestead box and I would like to add this piece of code to the `server` part of the Nginx config file for my site (in '/etc/ngnix/sites-available'):

```
location /storage/ {
    add_header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" "*";
}
```

I can type it in manually, but then it's gone every time I run `vagrant provision`.
What would be the best way to add this code during or after the provisioning?

**Update 1**

I found this article: https://medium.com/@maxxscho/laravel-homestead-with-custom-nginx-configurations-2e0fda4ba7dc
which brings me a step closer but now I have to figure out a way to place the custom serve-###.sh file outside the vendor folder. If anyone has thoughts on this, they are welcome as well!

**Update 2**

After fiddling some more I came up with a fairly decent solution:

1. Copy the `vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/serve-laravel.sh` to a folder outside the vendor folder (e.g. `./scripts`).
2. Edit the file to your needs.
3. Place some additional code in the `Vagrant` file to copy the script to the vendor folder before provisioning.

Add this to the `Vegrantfile`:

```
....
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

    config.trigger.before :provision do |trigger|
        trigger.info = "Copy custom scripts to vendor folder"
        trigger.run = {
            inline: "cp -r /scripts/* vendor/laravel/homestead/scripts/"
        }
    end
....
```

Any other solutions are still welcome!